# List Item is getting deleted Automatically when the list is a copy of another

Tags: java, android, arraylist, reference

I have a list say `list1` and then I am making a copy of `list1` as `list2`
Now if I remove one item from the `list1` then the same item from `list2` is also getting deleted.

```
ArrayList<Object> list1=new ArrayList<>();
//Then I am filling up only list1.
ArrayList<Object> list2=new ArrayList<>();
list1=list2;

for(i=0;i<Constants.list1.size();i++)
    Constants.list1.remove(2);
```

Then if I write this:

```
if(Constants.list2.size()==0)
  Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I am getting the Toast as ERROR.

I want to know whether copying one list to another makes them point to the same reference or not?

Comment: instead of assign (list1=list2) use list2.addAll(list1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not "copying":

```
list1 = list2;
```

It is making both variables (`list1` and `list2`) point to the same List object. So changes are made to the same list object, regardless of which variable is used to reference it.

To make a copy of the list, you can use:

```
list1= new ArrayList<>(list2);
```

Or copy element by element:

```
for(i=0;i < list2.size();i++)
    list1.add(list2.get(i));
```

Comment: So what I was doing was making a shallow copy?

Comment: No you were not "copying", you simply made the two variables point to the same object (no copy whatsoever). That's like calling the same person by 2 names (John and Smith). When you make John happy, Smith is happy too (possibly a lame analogy, but that's the idea).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have two references (`list1`, `list2`)pointing  to same memory object. It is a result of `list1=list2` assignment.

If you want to make a clone of the initial list you need to use:

```
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicate values first you need to clear the arraylist `list2.clear();`  then  copy full arraylist

```
 ArrayList<Object> list1=new ArrayList<>();
 //Then I am filling up only list1.
 ArrayList<Object> list2=new ArrayList<>();
 list2.clear();    //Before add value clear the arraylist 
 list2.addAll(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a standalone copy of your list would be with using the clone function and casting it to the expected type:

Replace:

```
list1 = list2;
```

With this:

```
list1 = (ArrayList<Object>)list2.clone();
```